# Java web service method receiving null argument from C# client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, glassfish-3

I'm working on a Java 6 application server which has a web service for receiving a SOAP messages containing an HL7 message. The Java application runs on Glassfish 3.1. The client is a third-party developed C# application (which runs on the Microsoft .net 4.0 framework) and it is sending these SOAP messages to the Java server.

My initial issue was that the client was unable to parse the WSDL generated by the server. I have since resolved that by implementing my own custom WSDL and tuning it accordingly. This allowed the client to parse the WSDL and send SOAP messages to my Java server application.

However, each time a message is received on the server side, the parameter (named "putXML") is receiving a `null` value.

The Glassfish server log shows the following when a message is received:

```
Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header: http://MyProject.MyPackage/putHL7Data
Received Message: null
```

Here is the custom WSDL that I created and associated with my SOAP web service:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions
      targetNamespace="http://MyProject.MyPackage/"
      xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
      xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
      xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
      xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
      xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
      xmlns:tns="http://MyProject.MyPackage/" 
      xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" 
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" 
      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
   <wsdl:types>
      <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://MyProject.MyPackage/">
         <s:element name="putHL7Data">
            <s:complexType>
               <s:sequence>
                  <s:element name="putXML" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
               </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
         </s:element>
         <s:element name="putHL7DataResponse">
            <s:complexType>
               <s:sequence>
                  <s:element name="return" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
               </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
         </s:element>
      </s:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="putHL7DataSoapIn">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:putHL7Data"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="putHL7DataSoapOut">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:putHL7DataResponse"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="MyHandlerSoap">
      <wsdl:operation name="putHL7Data">
         <wsdl:input message="tns:putHL7DataSoapIn"/>
         <wsdl:output message="tns:putHL7DataSoapOut"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="MyHandlerSoap" type="tns:MyHandlerSoap">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="putHL7Data">
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="MyHandler">
      <wsdl:port name="MyHandlerPort" binding="tns:MyHandlerSoap">
         <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And here is the Java web service:

```java
@WebService(serviceName = "MyHandler", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/MyHandler.wsdl")
public class MyHandler {
   @WebMethod(operationName = "putHL7Data")
   public String putHL7Data(@WebParam(name = "putXML") String xml) {
      // Handle message
   }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

What can I do to fix the Java web service so that it properly receives a non-null value?

Is this an issue with the client? If so, would I need to create some sort of interceptor?

**Update**

Today I tried creating a quick C# client which uses my Java SOAP web service. Below is the code:

```c#
namespace TestSoap
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceReference1.MyHandlerSoapClient ws = new ServiceReference1.MyHandlerSoapClient();
            string result = ws.putHL7Data("Test");    
            Console.WriteLine("Response: " + result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this client, I receive the same `null` value in the parameter when I was expecting to see the `Test` string. Also, I'm expecting `result` to contain a response string but it too is returning a `null` value.

Remember, I cannot modify the third-party C# client application. Is there anything I can do on the Java end?

**Update 2**

I recently added a handler chain class which is capturing and logging the raw SOAP messages. The message being sent by the client looks like this:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <putHL7Data xmlns="http://MyProject.MyPackage/">
      <putXML>... Encoded XML Here ...</putXML>
    </putHL7Data>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: It seems likely that the server is receiving null because the client is including the parameter in the request.

Comment: @DwB I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The source language has zero impact on the web service call.  If service call a parameter is null in the server it is because it was sent as null from the client.

Comment: @DwB I know for a fact that the client is sending a non-null string.

Comment: Have you captured the HTTP request? You can only know that it is sending a non-null string if you captured the request.  Assuming that this is true, the null can only be the result of either a failure in the translation from the xml in the HTTP request to the call to the java code.  If this is the case, I suspect that the parameter in question was encoded incorrectly at the client.  for example.  server expects <blammy value="kpow"/> and the client sends <blammy>kpow</blammy>

Comment: @DwB I have not seen the actual message. As a work around, I have in place a C# application which is acting as a proxy. It is receiving the message, repackaging it, and sending it to the Java web service. Someone else wrote this proxy and it's creating a bottle neck so I'm trying to remove it and have the two end points communicate directly.

Comment: try downloading a free http proxy testing tool to capture the http request.  you need to identify if the problem is in the client or in the server.  if you capture the request you will be able to see if the parameter in question is present and encoded correctly.

Comment: @DwB I determined that the issue is on the Java server side. The Java web service tester is also causing the "XML" parameter to be null. I also added a handler chain class which is logging the raw SOAP message from the client (see "Update 2" above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After getting pointed in the right direction by [@dlawrence](https://stackoverflow.com/users/948160/dlawrence), I was able to solve my issue. As I mentioned in the question, I still needed to use a custom built wsdl. I only needed to make a few changes to the wsdl and the Java code to solve the issue.

Here's a diff representing my changes to the wsdl:

```
--- /tmp/a  2011-09-19 15:05:21.132065003 -0400
+++ /tmp/b  2011-09-19 14:41:28.302064999 -0400
@@ -15,11 +15,11 @@
       xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <wsdl:types>
-      <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://MyProject.MyPackage/">
+      <s:schema targetNamespace="http://MyProject.MyPackage/">        
          <s:element name="putHL7Data">
             <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
-                  <s:element name="putXML" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
+                  <s:element name="putXML" type="s:string" form="qualified" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </s:sequence>
             </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
@@ -47,6 +47,6 @@
    <wsdl:binding name="MyHandlerSoap" type="tns:MyHandlerSoap">
       <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
       <wsdl:operation name="putHL7Data">
-         <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
+         <soap:operation soapAction="http://MyProject.MyPackage/putHL7Data" style="document"/>
          <wsdl:input>
             <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
```

Basically this was a three part fix...
1). I needed to remove the `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute from the `<s:schema>` tag.
2). Then I had to add the attribute `form="qualified"` on my `<s:element name="putXML" ...>` tag.
3). Finally, I needed to make sure I had the attribute `soapAction="http://MyProject.MyPackage/putHL7Data"` on my `<soap:operation>` tag.

Here's a diff representing my changes to the Java web method:

```
--- /tmp/a  2011-09-19 14:57:49.582065002 -0400
+++ /tmp/b  2011-09-19 15:00:06.942065007 -0400
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 @WebService(serviceName = "MyHandler", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/MyHandler.wsdl")
 public class MyHandler {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "putHL7Data")
-   public String putHL7Data(@WebParam(name = "putXML") String xml) {
+   public String putHL7Data(@WebParam(name = "putXML", targetNamespace="http://MyProject.MyPackage/") String xml) {
       // Handle message
    }
 }
```

As you can see, all I had to do was add the `targetNamespace` attribute to my `@WebParam`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried removing the @WebParam attribute? It shouldn't be required as there is no ambiguity with your web service here and it's possible you need to set the targetNamespace in order for it to correctly find the attribute.

Comment: I tried removing the "@WebParam" but there was no effect. Where would the "targetNamespace" go? Inside the "@WebParam" definition?

Comment: Yes, it should be an attribute of @WebParam.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! I was able to figure out how to tweak my custom wsdl by seeing what adding "targetNamespace" does to the generated wsdl's. I will post my own answer soon explaining what I did to resolve my issue.

Comment: had similar problem, adding targetNamespce to WebParam helped

Answer (score 2):

i have the same Message in my glassfish console. In my android project with ksoap function i changed the following code:

```
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapReq);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url,timeOut);
try{

        if (headers!=null){
            // original code // my headers are null
            httpTransport.call("http://service.iswitch.com/", soapEnvelope,headers);
        }else{
            httpTransport.call("\"http://service.iswitch.com/"\", soapEnvelope);
        }
        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
        if (result.hasProperty("moveResult"))
        {
```

....
it works ... );

the class i generated with http://www.wsdl2code.com